# Android Json parsing Error

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

org.json.JSON Exception : End of input at character 0

json parrsing data ,here is a link from i get data 
https://api.myjson.com/bins/1d3ei7  . use button in menu to refresh .
no thing show in activty .no thing show in activty .no thing show in activty no thing show in activty .no thing show in activty .no thing show in activty no thing show in activty .no thing show in activty .no thing show in activty .no thing show in activty .no thing show in activty .no thing show in activty

```
here is java class




 import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private String TAG = "MTAG";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvbio);




                //    new JsonTask().execute("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1d3ei7");


        }


       public  class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,List<Bio>>{
           @Override
           protected List<Bio> doInBackground(String... params) {
               HttpURLConnection connection=null;
               BufferedReader reader=null;
               try{

                   URL url=new URL(params[0]);
                  connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                   connection.connect();
                   InputStream stream=connection.getInputStream();
                   reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                   StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
                   String line="";
                   while (reader.readLine()!=null){
                       buffer.append(line);
                   }
                   String finalJson=buffer.toString();


                   JSONObject parentObject=new JSONObject(finalJson);


                   JSONArray parentArray=parentObject.getJSONArray("Bio");
                   List<Bio> bioList=new ArrayList<>();

                   for (int i=0; i<parentArray.length();i++){
                       JSONObject finalobject=parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       Bio bio=new Bio();

                       bio.setId(finalobject.getInt("id"));
                       bio.setFirst_name(finalobject.getString("first_name"));
                       bio.setGender(finalobject.getString("gender"));
                       bio.setImage(finalobject.getString("image"));



                     bioList.add(bio);
                   }
                   return bioList;
               }
               catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               return null;
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(List<Bio> bios) {
               super.onPostExecute(bios);
           }
       }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
           // return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            int id=item.getItemId();
            if (id==R.id.refresh){
                new JsonTask().execute("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1d3ei7");
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }



here is layout 




 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.offline.networking.MainActivity">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvbio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what exception you are getting?post logcat

Comment: you are accessing wrong key names for image check it once

Comment: no thing showing in logcat , i want to show data in list

Comment: do some reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to post

Comment: on debuging show this error: 0

 

org.json.JSON Exception : End of input at character 0

Comment: what will be right key for image

Answer (score 0):

Parse your json like this:

```
String finalJson=buffer.toString();
   JSONArray array=new JSONArray(finalJson);
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                         Bio bio=new Bio();
                        JSONObject finalObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                       bio.setId( finalObject.getInt("id"));
                        bio.setFirst_name(finalObject.getString("first_name"));
                        bio.setGender(finalObject.getString("gender"));
                        bio.setImage(finalObject.getString("photourl"));
bioList.add(bio);
                    }
```

Hope this will help you out..

Comment: for image key is "photourl"

Comment: now show  Bio can not applied on  bio.setId( finalObject.get("id"));

Comment: what is the datatype of the setId ?

Comment: datatype of the setId is int here is class    Bio  int id;
    String first_name;
    String gender;
    String image;

Comment: use bio.setId(finalObject.getInt("id"));

Comment: for image what datatype , like int for integer

Comment: String ,beacause data of the photourl in the json is string

Comment: bio.setId( finalObject.getInt("id"));
                        bio.setFirst_name(finalObject.getString("first_name"));
                        bio.setGender(finalObject.getString("gender"));
                        bio.setImage(finalObject.getString("photourl"));

Comment: still not run     java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

As per @Deepak Rana answer parsing is correct, but in your code getting null in String line

find the below code for connection and parsing

```
private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

public  class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,List<Bio>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Bio> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection=null;
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        try{

            URL url=new URL(params[0]);
            connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        connection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    getResponse = String.valueOf(response.append(inputLine));
                }
                in.close();

                // print result
                System.out.println(response.toString());
            } else {
                System.out.println("some error");
            }
            String finalJson=getResponse.toString();

            JSONArray parentArray=new JSONArray(finalJson);
            List<Bio> bioList=new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i=0; i<parentArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject finalobject=parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Bio bio=new Bio();

                bio.setId(finalobject.getInt("id"));
                bio.setFirst_name(finalobject.getString("first_name"));
                bio.setGender(finalobject.getString("gender"));
                bio.setImage(finalobject.getString("photourl"));

                bioList.add(bio);
            }
            return bioList;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```